# Moved my project folder to another location and now xcworkspace wont open with my main project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I just moved the folder where the entire project is located inside and after that when i try to launch my project with Xcode through the xcworkspace file, it just opens with the pod files ignoring my main project. Is there any way to reattach them?

Answer (score 0):

With finder go the folder where your project is located. You can find it directly from Xcode if you click on the project file at the Navigator (left side of the screen) and the on the inspector (right) click on the arrow next to the file path and it will open the folder.

Then right click on the project file (somename.xcodeproj)and show package content. Then open project.pbxproj file with a text editor. Once opened you should find for lines with ** >>>>, ==== or <<<< ** symbols and remove the full lines. (I recommend you to make a copy of the file before touching anything). Save it, close everything and restart Xcode again. It should be ok.